# Error when running sitespeed.io with chrome : Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, graphite

I was running this command on the terminal

`$ sitespeed.io -u http://cybercom.com  -b chrome`
but always facing this error, I have tried many times but in vain cannot figure out the problem

`message: 'unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.16.333243 (0bfa1357514444f1ddb82bf70944f96),platform=Linux 3.13.0-65-generic x86_64)'`

knowing that

1-Os version :
Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

2-my google chrome version is

`$ google-chrome -version`
  Google Chrome 46.0.2490.71

3-chrome driver version

`$ chromedriver -version`
ChromeDriver 2.10.267518

but in the message error it is "Driver info: chromedriver=2.16.333243" .... I didn´t understand why they aren´t the same version ?

Google chrome version is not supported neither with chromedriver=2.16 nor with ChromeDriver 2.10.

```
----------ChromeDriver v2.16 (2015-06-08)----------
Supports Chrome v42-45

----------ChromeDriver v2.10 (2014-05-01)----------
Supports Chrome v33-36
```

what should I do in this case ?

I appreciate your help . Thx

Comment: Did you install chromedriver as separate package?

Comment: yes i have following this instruction when i`ve installed it 
http://yizeng.me/2014/04/20/install-chromedriver-and-phantomjs-on-linux-mint/

Comment: From what I know chromedriver is provided by google chrome package. So maybe removing that custom chromedriver pacakge would help?

Comment: but in the sitespeed.io site , there is that i should install chromedriver so i could collect metrics from chrome  https://www.sitespeed.io/documentation/browsers/#chrome

Comment: Did you download and install package with proper architecture? Maybe try remove them all and install once again.

Comment: yeah , I`m sure that i´ve installed them with the same architecture.
I don´t want to remove them all , i want to let this choice til the end .